# OneToMany Bad primary key column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with new created table in application. I want to set primary key on dashboard_id and I've problem with relation. Why I get this? I have OneToMany, One dashboard, many groups. What should I do? What's wrong with it?
In Dashboard_groups table I've groups_id as PK and I want dashboard id.

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Dashboard.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "dashboard_groups", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groups_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "dashboard_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@JsonBackReference(value = "group- dashboard")
private Dashboard dashboard;
```

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dashboard", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "groups- dashboard")
    private List<Group> groups= new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is not to use a join table. Just use a foreign key in a `Group`.

```
@Entity
class Dashboard {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dashboard", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Group> groups;

}

@Entity
class Group{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Dashboard dashboard;

}
```

if you want to use a join table you shouldn't use `mappedBy`.

```
@Entity
class Dashboard {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Group> groups;

}

@Entity
class Group{


}
```